# Error 'enemytype' is not null here & use of unassigned variable 'enemytype'

Tags: c#, null

```
using static System.Console;
int enemy;
string enemytype;
string Juggernaut, Swiftster, Samurai;
Random random = new Random();

int d6 = random.Next(0, 6);
int d5 = random.Next(1, 5);
int d4 = random.Next(1, 4);
int d3 = random.Next(1, 3);
WriteLine("Welcome to the... DICE DOME! Your battle begins NOW! Press any key to roll the magical 3 sided dice to determine who you'll be fighting:");
ReadKey();
enemy = d3;
if (enemy == 1)
{
    enemytype = "Juggernaut";
}
else if (enemy == 2)
{
    enemytype = "Swiftster";
}
else if (enemy == 3)
{
    enemytype = "Samurai";
}
else
{
    //
}

WriteLine("=====================================================================");
WriteLine("You rolled a " + d3 + ", you will be battling " + enemytype + "!");
WriteLine("=====================================================================");
```

I'm expecting `enemytype` in the last line to read out either `Juggernaut`, `Swiftster` or `Samurai` but all I get is two errors. I've tried changing the string to a value and changing the if statements to if + else if + else statements. I'm not sure how to get it all working correctly. The only error is the unassigned variable and `enemytype` is not null here errors.

Comment: You need to initialise `enemytype` or set it in the `else` clause. And, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please not that `int d3 = random.Next(1, 3);` will only assign either `1` or `2` to `d3`. Your `if` statement can only ever assign `"Juggernaut"` or `"Swiftster"`. I don't expect that's what you want.